# Unable to get jupyter/scipy-notebook running on docker

Tags: docker, python

I pulled the docker image and is up to date. When  I  run it it says that it's going to be accessible at 8888 on  my localhost but when  I try to  access it resource can't be found.

Here is the output:

```
sudo docker run jupyter/scipy-notebook #jupyter
[sudo] password for tech: 
Execute the command
[I 06:16:54.964 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[W 06:16:55.137 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended.
[I 06:16:55.195 NotebookApp] JupyterLab alpha preview extension loaded from /opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 06:16:55.211 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jovyan
[I 06:16:55.211 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 06:16:55.211 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/?token=8bc0bf76526f10c078aad705f48f80598fe17aade9897db8
[I 06:16:55.211 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 06:16:55.212 NotebookApp] 

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=8bc0bf76526f10c078aad705f48f80598fe17aade9897db8
```

what could I  be  doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Instead copy-paste and format it accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @DanCornilescu noted

Comment: `sudo docker run jupyter/scipy-notebook -p 8888:8888` and localhost port on host will work. As is it's accessible on localhost of the container only.

Comment: @Tensibai thanks for the insight.. there is syntactical error in your command. I have updated and explained it.

Comment: Just wrote it from memory :)

Comment: @SudipBhandari what if you would run the container in daemon mode (-d) - how to access the token then? docker logs did not work for me

Comment: @J.Doe did you try 'jupyter notebook list'.. it shows currently running servers and the respective tokens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with port mapping. After mapping local machine port 8888 to docker's 8888 I could launch the program in browser.

```
sudo docker run -p 8888:8888 jupyter/scipy-notebook
```